# Order of group element, 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, math, element

I am trying to write a function to find the order of an element of a group. I keep getting this message

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'.

Here is my code :

```
def order_group_element(G, x):
    if not ((IsSymmetricGroup(G) or IsCyclicGroup(G)) and x in G):
       raise ValueError
   identity = G.identity()
   if x == identity:
       return 1
   a = 2
   i = x
   while not i == identity:
       i = G[i]
       a = a + 1
   return a
```

My input would be similar to the following:

```
a = CyclicGroup(500)
print 'G[1] Order = ',order_group_element(a, a[1])
```

I get the error from this line in my function:

```
while not i == identity:
```

Comment: Can I see the CyclicGroup() definition?

Comment: Yeah - need a bit more info on `CyclicGroup` to be able to answer.

Comment: All I have been told about it is that it creates a cyclic group on n points for CyclicGroup(n). Not sure where to find its definition.

Comment: Since the line you quote as the origin of the error message does not refer to a `value` attribute, let's please also see the stack trace, since the error is most likely somewhere down that line.

Comment: @Andyjm09, I suggest you create a minimal working script that demonstrates your issue. This way we could duplicate your problem and suggest remedies. Reading http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing

```
i = G[i]
```

to

```
i = i * x
```

in the while loop, since multiplication has been defined in the groups package, something I was unaware of.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may consider editing your answer/question to demonstrate what your question actually was: it may help others on SO, and may boost your reputation.